# Chinese characters in plsql showing as ¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

The chinese characters are showing as ¿¿. I am using sql developer and I am executing the below script . the datatype for the column I am updating is  NVARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) column. I have the font set correctly as some of the columns still showing chinese and Korean. The insert/update works fine as standalone with N' But when using it as a script/procedure it is not working.

```
Declare
v_sql varchar2(2000);
Begin
 v_sql := q'[UPDATE a_table SET DATA_VALUE_ALT_TXT_new =    N'또는 귀하 또는 귀하의 처방자가 귀하의' WHERE id = 100]';
 execute immediate v_sql;
 commit;
end;
/
```

Below are the NLS parameters used and we will not be able to change this.

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16   NCHAR Character set

NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8ISO8859P1    Character set

How else can I update the column to properly insert the chinese characterset.

Comment: Which tool do you use? Are you sure, it is the [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/)? Which font did you select?

Comment: I am sure I am using sql developer and I am using Malgon Gothic , also tried SimSun fonts

Comment: Which encoding do you use in the tool?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to test your scenario -

```
create table A_TABLE 
 (id integer,
  DATA_VALUE_ALT_TXT_NEW varchar2(2000)
);

insert into A_TABLE values (100, null);

set serveroutput on
Declare
v_sql varchar2(2000);
Begin
 v_sql := q'[UPDATE a_table SET DATA_VALUE_ALT_TXT_new =    N'또는 귀하 또는 귀하의 처방자가 귀하의' WHERE id = 100]';
 execute immediate v_sql;
 commit;
end;
/

select * from A_TABLE;
```

It "works," at least as described in your question;

Results:

```
Table A_TABLE created.


1 row inserted.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


        ID
----------
DATA_VALUE_ALT_TXT_NEW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
----------------------
       100 
또는 귀하 또는 귀하의 처방자가 귀하의
```

Comment: Thank you.. My font is fine.. I see some other columns with chinese and korean text but I am unable to update via a script/procedure. I am able to insert chinese characters using N' but not as a script/procedure.. But standalone insert scripts and update scripts work fine

Comment: i simulated what you're doing, see my updated answer

Comment: Probably your character set is different from mine.. I agree it would work with a different character set and I am using WE8ISO8859P1 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: if you're worried about that define your column as NVARCHAR2 vs VARCHAR2